# MYSQL - Randomly Selecting a row where two users are not following each other?

Tags: php, mysql, database, random

I am building an app that aims to show a user a randomly selected user from a list that he/she may like to follow where they are not following each other already.

I have 2 tables one table has a list of users and the second table has 2 columns that show a "following" relationship.

**Table 1 user** - user_id, instagram_id, join_date

**Table 2 users_follow** - instagram_id_1, instagram_id_2

I was just wondering if anyone could point me in the right direction on how to create the join and select a random row where the 2 users are not following each other? I have tried a left join but without any luck so far.

This is the code so far

```
SELECT * 
FROM users
INNER JOIN  `user_follows` ON users.instagram_id = user_follows.instagram_id
WHERE user_follows.instagram_id !=  'insta123'
```

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Please leave some code, what you have so far.

Comment: Do you mean where two users are not following each other or neither user is following the other?

Comment: I think you would want an `OUTER JOIN`.

Comment: Yes ideally where two users are not following each other. So I have the id of user A and I need to find another user where the two are not following each other.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you make a sub query to get the list of your follower. Then user a LEFT JOIN and find those who are not follower by testing for NULL.

```
SELECT users.* from users
left join  
(
    SELECT 
        users_follows.instagram_id_2 as 'instagram_id'
    from users
    inner join users_follows on users.instagram_id=users_follows.instagram_id_1
    where users.instagram_id = 'insta123'
) as followers on users.instagram_id = followers.instagram_id
where followers.instagram_id is null
and users.instagram_id != 'insta123' # you can't follow yourself
```

I've tested it with a replica of your structure and it works fine.